# PHP PDO Not returning any data from other class

Tags: php, class, pdo

I have the following script that is not returning any thing at all, the best I've gotten is a var_dump to say bool(false).. There is nothing at all in my error_log and no exceptions are being thrown:

index.php:

```
require("php/bootstrap.php");
$campaign = new Campaign($_GET['campaign'], $mysql);
```

bootstrap.php:

```
define ("MYSQL_USER", "specialagent");
define ("MYSQL_PASS", "supertopsecret");
define ("MYSQL_HOST", "127.0.0.1");
define ("MYSQL_PORT", "3306");
define ("MYSQL_DB", "databasewithsecretinformation");


/* Auto include classes on instantiation */
function __autoload($class_name) {
    include 'classes/'.$class_name.'.php';
}

/* Connections */
try {
$mysql = new PDO("mysql:host=".MYSQL_HOST.";dbname=test", MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_PASS);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
die("There was a problem connecting to the database. Error: " . $e->getMessage());
}
```

Campaign.php

```
class Campaign {
protected $dbh;
private $campaign_id = "";
private $name = "";

public function __construct ($campaign_id, PDO $db) {

    //if ($campaign_id) {
        $this->setCampaignID($campaign_id);
        $this->dbh = $db;
        $this->loadCampaignInfo();
    //}
}


public function getCampaignID() {
    return $this->campaign_id;
}

public function setCampaignID($id) {
    $this->campaign_id = $id;
}

public function __destruct() {
    //$this->dbh = null;
}

public function loadCampaignInfo() {
    /* Get info from database */
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM campaigns WHERE campaign=:campaignID";

    try {
        echo "trying query...$sql<br />";
        if ($this->dbh instanceof PDO) {
            $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindParam(":campaignID", $this->campaign_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->execute();
            $row = $stmt->fetch();

            echo "Returned Data: ";
            var_dump($row);
        } else {
            echo "Not a valid PDO resource";
        }


    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Problem : " . $e->getMessage;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Other problem : " . $e->getMessage;
    }


    /* Set properties */
}
```

}

Output:

```
trying query...SELECT * FROM campaigns WHERE campaign=:campaignID
Returned Data: bool(false)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your code. Your constructor populates the campaignID based on `$_GET['campaign']`, as that's what you pass in. But your SQL's WHERE clause is `WHERE campaign='{$_GET['campaign']}'";
` - the output you've included shows that that is `:campaignID`. Are you passing in `:campaignID` through `$_GET`?

Comment: Sorry I changed the SQL to be more simplified and didn't fully change it back, edited post to show what it says now.

Comment: A couple of other thoughts - you're binding `campaignID` as a string; you might want to try binding it as an integer instead. Also, you should be able to get some data about why the query is failing with `var_dump($stmt->ErrorInto())` and `var_dump($this->dbh->ErrorInfo())`

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::ErrorInto() in /var/www/html/scripts/energy/classes/Campaign.php on line 100 

Also, I did echo get_class($stmt) and it returns PDO

Comment: oooops, typo - it's `ErrorInfo()` for both of them.

Comment: Ah yes, got it now. Changed to ErrorInfo() and it looks like its a database issue. Thanks everybody!

Comment: If you've got it fixed, could you add the solution as an answer (and accept it when you're able to)?

Comment: Sure thing, we are checking the database, gonna do a quick test then will mark it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has nothing to do with PDO.
`Returned Data: bool(false)` means no row were found to match condition.
Check your table if it contain the data and check input as well.
Check if you are getting the right class from autoload and all the stuff like that.

Also, change your bootstrap connection to

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

/* Connections */
$mysql = new PDO("mysql:host=".MYSQL_HOST.";dbname=test", MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_PASS);
$mysql->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
```

you may wish also to make the method less bloated too:

```
/* Get info from database */
public function loadCampaignInfo()
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM campaigns WHERE campaign=?";
    $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute([$this->campaign_id]);
    return $stmt->fetch();
}
```

Comment: Doesn't a boolean false mean that there was a problem with the query, and it failed?

Comment: I built the query in Heidi SQL then copied and pasted into the code. The SQL is sound. I will try your recommendations and post back. Thanks!

Comment: It is not about whatever Heidi SQL but about the database you are connecting with these credentials

Comment: Ok, I just signed into MySQL cli with those creds and the database doesn't appear in SHOW DATABASES. Let me change the privs and I'll get back

Answer (score -1):

The problem was that the user did not have the correct privileges to access the database, after Your Common Sense suggested the creds were the issue, logged into MySQL cli and noticed the database was not in SHOW DATABASES.

Thanks for the help everybody.

Comment: this answer renders question as too localized

Comment: also, the actual problem is that you weren't using db constant. otherwise error would be thrown at connect